# Can I make a foreach loop for every object hit by radius other than any object tagged with something?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, foreach, 2d

I was making a script with a collider2d in unity to check if the player was nearby so the enemy could move near him once he is detected in the range. This is a part of the code:

```
foreach(Collider2D player in hitPlayer) {
            PlayerNearby();
        }
```

I wanted to make a foreach loop where for each object that is not a player in hitPlayer, the enemy object will idle since this script is the walking animation StateMachineBehaviour script.

I tried to use the exclamation mark and equal signs in the foreach statement like so:

```
foreach(Collider2D !player in hitPlayer) {
            PlayerNearby();
        }
```

Can you please tell me what I did wrong and inform me of what to do?

Comment: Your syntax is not valid.
`player` in this case is just the identifier of the variable that is accessible inside the foreach-loop. It does in no way determine if the instance assigned to it belongs to a player or not.

You would need to check the variable _inside_ the loop to determine if it is a player or not, or filter the collection ahead of time.

Comment: @P.Magnusson How do you suggest I could do that? I already defined player as GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform ahead of time and I couldn't find any method to check if the object is the player using an if statement and I tried all loops and made a bool. They didn't work.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation for Collider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) it has an property of `gameObject` which would return the GameObject that the collider is attached to. You should be able to check the tags of that object to see if it's tagged with "Player", or compare it to the GameObject that you've already retreived with  `FindGameObjectWithTag(string)`

Comment: How exactly do you get those `hitPlayer`? If this is e.g. a `Physics.OverlapCircle` you can simply pass in a layer mask to only hit certain objects (your player) in the first place

Answer (score 0):

This Should work for you
Physics.OverlapCircleAll()

Example:

```
    void Update()
    {
        LayerMask layer = 5; //This should be the id of the player layer. You will find the id when the selection layer
        float radius = 3f; //This should be the radius for checking. Maybe make a public or [SerializeField] for this value and maybe add some gizmos
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, radius, layer); //Returns a list of objects hit
        foreach (Collider2D playerHit in colliders)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player in range " + playerHit.name);
            DoStuff()
        }

    }
```

Remember to read the docs if you don't understand a value or certain thing.
[Here are the docs.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html)